# Find a lower bound of $-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(1-2a+x)^2-8(-3-4a-3x-2ax)}-\frac{1}{4}(1-2a+x)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I have to find a lower bound (**that does not depend on $x$**) of the following quantity:
$$-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(1-2a+x)^2-8(-3-4a-3x-2ax)}-\frac{1}{4}(1-2a+x)$$
where $x\geq 0,\, a>0$.
Really I have tried to observe that:
$-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(1-2a+x)^2-8(-3-4a-3x-2ax)}-\frac{1}{4}(1-2a+x)>-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(1-2a+x)^2-8(-3-4a-3x-2ax)}=A$

but then I can't find a lower bound of A...can you help me?

Comment: You mean for a fixed $a>0$, chosen at the start?

Comment: Are you sure there is a lower bound valid for all $x$?

Comment: Yes I mean for a fixed $a>0$...then well i am trying to find a lower bound, but I am not sure it is possible....

Comment: Notice that the expression is bounded above by $ - 1/4 ( 1 - 2a + x) - 1/4 ( 1 - 2a + c)$. So there can be no lower bound. Perhaps check the term in the square root, seems there seems to be an otherwise redundant double negative.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be a fixed positive real. Let $x \geqslant 0$ be allowed to vary.

Let $A=2,\quad B=1-2a+x,\quad C=-3-4a-3x-2ax.$

Consider the quadratic $Ay^2+By+C=0.$

Then your expression is the left-hand root of this quadratic:
$$-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(1-2a+x)^2-4A(-3-4a-3x-2ax)}-\frac{1}{4}(1-2a+x).$$

(For we see that $A>0,\; C<-3,\; B^2-4AC>0$ for any $x$, and thus the parabola always has two roots.)

So I think you cannot have such a bound. For we can, by increasing $x$ more and more, move the axis of symmetry of the parabola further and further to the left. This must in turn push the left-hand root towards $-\infty$.

The axis of symmetry:  $\;y= \frac{-B}{2A}.$